# Remote desktop into a work computer from home - router setup

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, wireless-router

I need help setting up our router in our office, so I can connect remotely to a computer from home.

We have a small office inside a larger building. We connect to the internet through our router which is plugged in to a socket in the wall. The whole large building has 1 public IP and we don't have access managing this network. All we can set up is our private network behind our router.

Our router is a Asus RT N18u and we also have a prepaid internet SIM card and a USB dongle, which the router can use for secondary internet connection.

But I'm unable to get into our network from the outside.

I don't know if its even possible using this setup, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: connect to the internet through our router which is plugged in to a socket in the wall   ....... You should be able to replace this with a VPN router and set up access that way. Get your IT person / consultant to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution with the connectivity you have in place. Option # 1 is to use a 3rd party solution to get access to your devices. Google Chrome Remote Desktop or WebEx Anywhere will provide you with this access.

Option # 2 would be to invest in a separate Internet connection which will give you a public IP address. I do not know about the prepaid SIM card you have, usually they do not give you Public IP address. Your router supports OpenVPN, and here is a guide that will assist you in setting up remote access.

https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008713/